# Display profile pic from model in template in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I want to insert the user's image in the `src` field of `img` tag.But I'm not able to do it.
My code:

models.py

```py
class allusers(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='retest/static/images/')
```

views.py

```py
u = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

template

```html
<img src={{ u.allusers.avatar }} />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1, register static and media in settings correct way .

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/django/myproject/src/myproject/media'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_FILE_ROOT = '/srv/django/myproject/src/myproject/static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/srv/django/myproject/src/myproject/static',
)
```

2, call static and media urls in urls.py

```
from django.views.static import serve

url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, { 'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), 
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, { 'document_root': settings.STATIC_FILE_ROOT}),
```

3, Call avathar like this

```
<img src="{{ u.allusers.avatar.url }}" alt="Avathar"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I got an alternate solution

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the attibutes name, in that way:

`<img src={{ u.allusers.avatar.url }}`

Can check it in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/files/).

Note: that will works if `u.allusers` is a good reference, of which I have some doubt.

Comment: <img src= {{ u.allusers.avatar.url }} is not working

Comment: Maybe you need to use **name** and **path** attributes. What string you get in url attribute? Show their values and select which can works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use related_name in the OneToOne field to reference the allusers model through User.

```
 class allusers(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
```

template

```
<img src="{{ u.profile.avatar.url }}">
```