# Displaying images from ImageField

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I try to display the same image of a coin in 2 sections of my site (a list of articles and a gallery of coins). The only difference (I guess) is that from the articles page I call it by a foreign key while from the gallery I call it directly.

The image **is** displayed in the article list but **not** in the gallery.

Here is some code:

the models:

```
# coinCollection/models.py:
class coin(models.Model):
    #...
    coin_thumbnail = models.ImageField(max_length=500, upload_to = join(MEDIA_IMAGES_DIR, MEDIA_COINS_DIR), verbose_name='Miniature')
    #...

# blog/models.py:
class article(models.Model):
    #...
    article_money = models.ForeignKey(coin,
        null = True,
        on_delete = models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="money"
    )
```

the views:

```
# coinCollection/views.py:
class coinGallery(ListView):
    model = coin
    template_name = 'coinsCollection/gallery.html'
    context_object_name = 'coins_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        coin_list = coin.objects.values('id', 'coin_name', 'coin_millesime', 'coin_thumbnail').order_by('coin_name')

        paginator = Paginator(coin_list, 3) # Show n coins per page

        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            coins = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            coins = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            coins = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        return coins

# blog/views.py
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/articles.html'
    context_object_name = 'article_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        article_list = article.objects.order_by('-article_pub_date')
        paginator = Paginator(article_list, 3) # Show n articles per page

        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            articles = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            articles = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range, deliver last page of results.
            articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        return articles
```

and in the templates :

```
# gallery.html (Not displayed, empty var)
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ coin.coin_thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ coin.coin_name }}">

# articles.html (Displayed correctly)
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ article.article_money.coin_thumbnail.url }}">
```

Thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720099/display-profile-pic-from-model-in-template-in-django/43723212#43723212 . Check this

Comment: I checked, my media settings are registered correctly, otherwise no image would be displayed at all. My problem is that in one case the image is displayed but in the other it is not :-/ I don't understand why because I call the exact same entry in my database. It's just the way that's different.

Comment: how are you iterating que `queryset`'s in the template?

Comment: Yes, in both cases :) I checked the name of each context object and it's ok. Every field's got a value except in the gallery for coin_thumbnail.url... I also noticed that coin_thumbnail alone has the correct value. It's really strange that when accessing a foreign key everything works whereas it doesn't when accessing directly. Everything else is the same, unless I miss something...

Comment: Sorry I missread. I iterate with a basic for loop : `{% for coin in coins_list %}` and `{% for article in article_list %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `coinGallery` view, you've converted the queryset to `values()`. This turns the ImageFieldFile object `'coin_thumbnail'` into its string representation, i.e. `'myimage.jpg'`, and you can't use Django's convenience attribute `.url` with it. To use the `.url` attribute, just use `coin.objects.order_by()` instead of `coin.objects.values().order_by()`. Or if you prefer values then you'll need to join the `MEDIA_URL` to the coin_thumbnail file name to get the complete file path.

Answer (score 1):

values returns only the related path. Just use `{{MEDIA_URL}}{{coin.coin_thumbnail}}` on the template. (Beware of the appending slashes defined in your settings.py)

Comment: Thank you @Deniz !